# Pipeline does not get converted to PMML properly using JPMML and Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, pmml

I am using Pyspark and JPMML library to generate PMML models from my pipeline models. But I don't think it's generating properly. For testing this, I created two different pipeline models using the same dataset and the classifier as below.

```
pipeline = Pipeline(stages = [assembler, slicer,pca, binarizer,assembler2, formula,classifier])
pipeline2 = Pipeline(stages = [assembler, slicer, binarizer,assembler2, formula,classifier])
```

But when I generate the PMML file using the following code snippet, it outputs two identical files. Which means there is no difference between the models. I am confused. The generated PMML files should be different if it's converting properly right?

```
pipelineModel1 = pipeline.fit(df)
pmmlBytes = toPMMLBytes(spark, df, pipelineModel1)
with open('test.pmml','wb') as output:
output.write( pmmlBytes)

pipelineModel2 = pipeline2.fit(df)
pmmlBytes2 = toPMMLBytes(spark, df, pipelineModel2)
with open('test1.pmml','wb') as output:
output.write( pmmlBytes2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The generated PMML files should be different if it's converting properly right?

Not necessarily. It all depends on your classification function - it may happen that PCA generated columns are simply not included in the PMML document, because they do not "contribute" to separating the classes. To test this hypothesis, try different classification functions such as `DecisionTreeClassifier` vs. `LogisticRegression`.

Also, the only way to verify whether a PMML document is correct or not is to  execute it, and verify its results against the original Apache Spark(ML) results.

Comment: I have a question. Let's say some columns do not  contribute to the last output. But the preprocessing steps to the input data should be done regardless right? For an example, if I use vector slicing etc. in my preprocessing steps and include them in my pipeline, those information should be encoded in the PMML because it should apply the same operations to incoming data when predicting isn't it? But how come the same PMML is generated although the preprocessing steps are different?

Comment: There is no point in doing preprocessing on columns that aren't used by the mining function. It's just wasted compute cycles.